# How do I stop a file from downloading multiple times from a JavaScript Blob?

Tags: javascript

I am calling an API endpoint for a backend microservice that downloads an HTML file as the API data response. I'm using ReactJS and the Axios library to call the backend microservice, and I am getting a good response.

In the `.then` block of my code I am using a JavaScript Blob to handle the response data and save it as a HTML file. This block of the code basically takes the response from the API call and prepares the data as a downloadable link with a custom filename.

The download starts automatically when the `link.click()` portion of the block is executed.

However, the problem I encounter is the response is making my web browser download the same HTML file two times.

I am trying to figure out how to have the file download only once and NOT multiple times.

Here is my code:

```
  const callAPI = () => {
    Axios.post(api_endpoint, bodyArgs)
      .then((response) => {
        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
        const link = document.createElement("a");
        link.href = url;
        link.setAttribute("download", `${company}_${startDate}_${endDate}.html`);
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
        alert(
          "Sorry, there was an error processing your request. Please check the dates of your report and try again!"
        );
      });
  };
```

Is there a problem in the `.then` block of my code, or is this a web browser specific issue? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the click event fires twise

try

```
  const callAPI = () => {
    Axios.post(api_endpoint, bodyArgs)
      .then((response) => {
        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
        const link = document.createElement("a");
        link.href = url;
        link.setAttribute("download", `${company}_${startDate}_${endDate}.html`);
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
        link.remove();
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
        alert(
          "Sorry, there was an error processing your request. Please check the dates of your report and try again!"
        );
      });
  };
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I actually did something rather silly by calling the callAPI function twice. In my Form component, I had an onSubmit prop that passed a handleSubmit function that called fired off my callAPI() function. I also had a Button component nested in my Form component that had a onSubmit prop that fired callAPI(). Therefore, whenever I clicked the button, the callAPI function was triggered twice.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that I had my callAPI function written twice in my code. I have a Form component that has an onSubmit prop, and in that prop I have a handleSubmit function executes my callAPI() function.

I also have a Button component nested in my Form component that has a onSubmit prop that fired callAPI(). Therefore, whenever I clicked the button, the callAPI function was triggered twice...once through the Form component, and another through the Button component.

I removed the onSubmit prop in my Button component, and just let my Form component handle the submit action, and that solved my issue.